# installing ruby on rails on passenger dosn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

is there a good and simple installation guide how to install phusion passenger on my apache2 and then install ruby on rails?

I'm using debian 7

i've done point 2.31 and 2.3.2
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rubygems_generic_install

then I tried this: $ gem install rails

and got this error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `-dev` package installed, so it can't find mkmf.

Run `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev` to install the dev package for 1.9.1

Comment: is it possible to upgrade to the newest ruby version? and when how can I do this

Comment: Sure, the current stable release is 2.2.0, so just run the same command but use `2.2.0` instead of `1.9.1`

Comment: thats all? don't have to say the passenger which version he should take?

Comment: That's all you need to solve this problem... your error is just the missing mkmf. If you have more issues when setting up, you should probably address them in separate questions.

Comment: I tried to download 2.2.0 but it says package couldn't be found ... 
`sudo apt-get install ruby2.2.0-dev'